# How to create a setup in xcode/iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I'm wondering how I can add some kind of setup to my App so when the user launches the App it asks a couple of questions and based on those questions it redirects to a specific view and the next time the app launches it will continue there again.

Is there any way to achieve this, because I'm unsure where I should start searching for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did something similar in my last project. There the user had the option to use the application connected with facebook or not. For storing the decision of the user I used a key/value pair in the `NSUserDefaults`. It's very easy to read/write and its persistently stored in the apps filesystem.

**I first checked the NSUserDefaults if the key/value pair already exists.**

1. **If not**, I did a redirection to a ViewController containing the two buttons (With FB/No FB)
2. Then depending on the selection of the user I setted the NSUserDefault key.

---

1. **If yes**, I did read the NSUserDefaults and get the value of the key.
2. Depending on the loaded value I redirected him to the FB ViewController or the the normal one.

Here a short example of reading the NSUserDefaults:

```
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *myString = [prefs stringForKey:@"keyToLookupString"];
```

Here a short example of writing the NSUserDefaults:

```
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[prefs setObject:@"TextToSave" forKey:@"keyToLookupString"];
```

I guess the only difference to your application is that you have several values to store but for that you can still use the `NSUserDefaults`. You could also use the `CoreData` to store the information but I think in that case using the `NSUserDefaults` is the way to go.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I would like to do, can you share some sample code of your project? And where should I implent these. Sorry for asking but I'm new to xcode so I'm not sure what to do with this code since this looks like saving a text object.

Comment: I'm sorry I can't give you the code. I left this company and I cannot access the code anymore ;). But I can give you some more hints to look up. This is pretty standard and you should find to all of the following topics plenty of information. You have to create different ViewControllers (Containing the questions / The view you wanna go after the user answered the questions). NSUserDefaults is the storage where you store the answers. All the code above is everything you need to read/write to this storage. Then its simple push/pop of ViewControllers depending on the answers of the user.

Comment: Yeah thats how I implemented it. The check if there is already data in the NSUserDefaults I did in the AppDelegate.m file. Depending on the value set in the NSUserDefaults I redirected to a specific ViewController. Exactly, the buttons in the ViewController are bind to an action which then will do a write to the NSUserDefaults.